# deltastreamer.HoodieDeltaStreamer exceptio: Filesystem closed

Tags: apache-spark, data-lake, apache-hudi

I am using HoodieDeltaStreamer to connect kafka and store data to hoodie table
Hudi version : 0.10.1
Spark : 3.2.4
Hadoop : 3.3.5

Only one spark-submit job is running

cmd :

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.hudi.utilities.deltastreamer.HoodieDeltaStreamer "file://$HUDI_HOME/docker/hoodie/hadoop/hive_base/target/hoodie-utilities.jar" --continuous --table-type COPY_ON_WRITE --source-class org.apache.hudi.utilities.sources.AvroKafkaSource --source-ordering-field submit_date --target-base-path "hdfs://172.16.0.132:9000/data-lake/raw-zone/tables/temp_cow" --target-table temp_cow --props "file://$HUDI_HOME/hudi-utilities/src/test/resources/delta-streamer-config/kafka-source-Table_May_live_v3.properties" --schemaprovider-class org.apache.hudi.utilities.schema.SchemaRegistryProvider --source-limit 50000 > /data/data-lake/logs/pull_from_kafka_topic1.log 2>&1 &
```

StackTrace :

```
2023-06-27 12:23:37,238 INFO sources.AvroKafkaSource: About to read 0 from Kafka for topic :Table_May_live_v3
2023-06-27 12:23:37,238 INFO deltastreamer.DeltaSync: No new data, source checkpoint has not changed. Nothing to commit. Old checkpoint=(Option{val=Table_May_live_v3,0:200000}). New Checkpoint=(TempLMSTable_May_live_v3,0:200000)
2023-06-27 12:23:37,240 ERROR deltastreamer.HoodieDeltaStreamer: Shutting down delta-sync due to exception
java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.checkOpen(DFSClient.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1729)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1752)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1749)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1760)
    at org.apache.hudi.utilities.deltastreamer.DeltaSync.refreshTimeline(DeltaSync.java:244)
    at org.apache.hudi.utilities.deltastreamer.DeltaSync.syncOnce(DeltaSync.java:288)
    at org.apache.hudi.utilities.deltastreamer.HoodieDeltaStreamer$DeltaSyncService.lambda$startService$0(HoodieDeltaStreamer.java:640)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

A  "`Filesystem closed`" typically means the Hadoop FileSystem instance being used by your application was closed while the application was still trying to use it.
You can see an example of this error with [`apache/hudi` issue 227](https://github.com/apache/hudi/issues/227)

> My guess is there is some other piece of code calling fs.close(). fs client is shared across the jvm
>
> I changed the core of spark to 1 , the error gone away. May I ask why can not set the core more than 1 ?
>
> Issue is tracked in [#254](https://github.com/apache/hudi/issues/254) . Basically, its a race in how the filesystem object gets closed across threads with cores > 2 .

That particular error was supposed to be fixed with [PR 620](https://github.com/apache/hudi/pull/620), Hudi 0.5.2+.

> General practice for spark apps is to *not* call `fs.close()` at all and Hudi should be no different.. However as @bvaradar pointed out to me, may be its worth calling `super.close()` just in case.

In general, try and avoid sharing `FileSystem` instances between threads: If possible, each thread should have its own `FileSystem` instance. This can help avoid concurrency issues.

If your application detects that the `FileSystem` instance has been closed (e.g., by catching the `IOException`), it could try to recreate it.

If you're using Java, consider using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) or similar constructs to ensure that resources are cleaned up properly.

Comment: I have gone throught the github issues but my version is newer so ideally my version should not have such issues. Also I am running just spart-submit with HoodieDeltaStreamer code with one instance only

Comment: @AnkitBansal So maybe there is another process which would still keep a handle opened, while your one instance spart-submit is trying to close the file?